# How can I retrieve DNS IP of my ISP on Windows with C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to implementing a DNS client according to rfc1035.
Instead of using Google DNS, I would rather query DNS cache of my ISP first.
Though I can use `ipconfig /all` to retrieve it manually, I wanna know if there is a way to retrieve ISP's DNS cache IP through C++.

Say my router IP is 192.168.0.1, what should I do with it?

Comment: Use the [GetAdapterAddresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915(v=VS.85).aspx) function to obtain the addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ron pointed out in the comments, call `GetAdapterAddresses`. Despite the name, it returns a structure which contains `FirstDnsServerAddress`. This is the first DNS server from a linked list of DNS servers.